# NoMethodError: undefined method `synchronize' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::GeneratedAttributeMethods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a project where we are migrating from an old ruby web api (not rails) that was pulling in activeSupport and activeRecord 4.1.8 and using resque 1.25.2 for jobs to a new rails 4.2.4 project using resque 1.25.2 for job processing as well. Everything has been going pretty smoothly until I started a resque work to process jobs and I got:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'synchronize' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::GeneratedAttributeMethods`

This error is only thrown when `User.find_by_id` or `User.new` is called within the context of a worker process. This same error is thrown when calling several other models as well but not all of them. `Company.new`, for example, doesn't throw the error and if I rename the `User` model to say `Companya` the error goes away... Running ruby 2.2.3 on the rails app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by replacing all the calls to `.find_by_id` with `.find`. `.find` will always use the `id` column and does not have the overhead of the dynamic finder methods.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've encountered the issue once...

The exception would be raised when Rails failed to find the method that was generated dynamically. So the case I can imagine is that Rails (ActiveRecord) did not define the methods dynamically.

The matters which should be checked are...

1. restarting resque and KVS.
2. models' class names, parent classes (should be ActiveRecord::Base) and migration files if that follow Rails naming conventions correctly. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions
3. reset and migrate again in all environments with the argument like `$ bin/rake db:migrate:reset RAILS_ENV=production`
4. stopping the Spring once by `$ bin/spring stop`. (It restarts automatically when the next `bin` command is called.)

hmm...Can you use those methods in `rails console`?

Hope it would help...!

Comment: all of the models work correctly in `rails console` and in the context of `rails server` just not in the worker context.

Comment: Maybe you can try to enqueue a job to KVS (you use redis?) by resque and check the jobs in redis in `rails console`. Or you can manage logs by using `Resque::Failure module`. See: https://github.com/resque/resque#failure

Answer (score 0):

`synchronize' error happens when the related gem is not up to date. I belive if you update your installed gems then the issue would be resolved.